# NDK - Swig - Android Studio - No implementation found error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I created an Android Application that uses the NDK.
Under the jni directory I have bunch of C++ files and a .c and .h file under C directory. I created the JNI interfaces using the swig tool over the C++ code. So far so good. 
The application is compiling file and I was able to run the application and invoke an API from the C++ class.

Now I want to make a static library using the .c and .h file and include that in my Android.mk instead of compiling all the files into a single .so file.
I created a new Android.mk file and included .c and created a Static Library.
When I compile the code i can see the .a file is created.

I included the following lines to Android.mk file under jni directory.

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

... remove the .c file from the LOCAL_SRC_FILES variable.

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libhello
```

After this changes, 
I can compile the code and launch the application. But when ever I invoke the API from the C++ class( same function which worked earlier), now the application crashes with an exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found

- I Verified to see if .so file is available in the apk and that does not seems to be the problem.
- Checked that the .so file is loading correctly.
- Instead of specifying "include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)"
  I also tried by directly included "#include C/Android.mk"
- I tried searching for simi

Still the application fails with the same exception. 
Appreciate if somebody can help me resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Ajala

I'm providing the Android.mk file content for the project

```
/*********************************************/
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)



include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := SWIGCPlusTester

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cxx .cpp


MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES := 
$(wildcard $(MY_PATH)/*.cpp)
MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
$(wildcard $(MY_PATH)/*.cxx)


LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
$(subst jni/, , $(MY_LOCAL_SRC_FILES))

LOCAL_LDLIBS :=-llog

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libhello

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
/*********************************************/
```

I'm also attaching the Android.mk file content that is present in the "C" directory.

```
/*********************************************/
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH_INCLUDE := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := hello

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
/*********************************************/
```

I created the mk file based on the sample https://code.google.com/p/razzlegames-android-ndk-tutorial/
Hope this information helps to identify the issue.

Comment: I'm providing the Android.mk file contact for the project